# Rails 4 App : How to set up the same application along with PSQL Database in New System?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, psql

I am working with a Rails 4 app, I am using PSQL both in my development and production. Due to some reason I have to work with a new computer/laptop so I set up Rails environment in it and cloned my app into it, but what I really require is that, I need my existing databse with data in it, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to create a dump on system 1 and restore it on system 2, here are the steps:

1. `sudo -u postgres pg_dump <DB_NAME> > dump` - creating a file `dump`
2. Copy this file via dropbox or whatever to another system.
3. `sudo -u postgres psql <DB_NAME> < dump` - copy the new created dump to new system.

#### Note:

You should have empty created database on your new system, or you can use dataonly dump passing the `--data-only` to `pg_dump` command.
Also you can read documentation for [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) to find any other options which you might need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy